Why does an atom become positively charged when it shares its lone pair?
Why does an atom become positively charged when it shares its lone pair?
In NH3, Nitrogen doesn't get positive charge when forming covalent bond with Hydrogens. But why does it get positive charge with it shares with the fourth Hydrogen to form Coordinate bond?
Those 2 electrons (1 lone Pair) from valence shell of Nitrogen are being shared by both of them, just like covalent bond.
And moreover, even if Nitrogen is supposed positive charge, it should have +2 charge and not +1 charge since it is taking 2 electrons out of it's valence shell and giving it to Hydrogen.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32554/is-there-any-way-of-representing-a-dative-coordinate-covalent-bond https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10215/the-bond-in-coordination-complexes

Formally ammonia plus a positively charged proton gives ammonium. The positive charge comes from the proton.

To start with the last comment. No the formal charge of the nitrogen wil not be $+2$, as the $2$ electrons (from the lone pair) are not 'given' to the hydrogen. The nitrogen still has "$1$" electron 'left' from the lone pair when it forms $\ce{NH4+}$.
Formal charge is just a definition, following some simple rules/steps you should be able to determine the formal charge of any atom. Below are the structures of ammonium and ammonia.

First for ammonium:
Nitrogen has $5$ valence electrons, there are $0$ non-bonding electrons, and there are $4$ bonds ($8$ electrons). This means that $\ce{N}$ has a formal charge of: $5-0-\frac{8}{2}=+1$
Now for ammonia:
Nitrogen has $5$ valence electrons, there are $2$ non-bonding electrons (the lone pair), and there are $3$ bonds ($6$ electrons). This means that $\ce{N}$ has a formal charge of: $5-2-\frac{6}{2}=0$
Lastly, there is also another way to determine the charge of nitrogen. That is by using the rule of thumb, the octet rule. Main group elements (like nitrogen) tend to bond such that there are 8 electrons in the valence shell. For ammonium, there are $8$ valence electrons. $4$ are 'on' nitrogen and each hydrogen has $1$. This means nitrogen has $1$ electron less than it would normally have in its valence shell ($5$) meaning that it must have a formal charge of $+1$.
